# confused by PHP's bcmul() scale

Tags: php, bcmath

Why is this outputting `87.5` and not  `87.50`?

```
<?php

$quantity = 25;
switch ($quantity)
{
    case ($quantity <= 50):
        $price = 3.50;
        break;
    case ($quantity <= 100):
        $price = 3.00;
        break;
    default:
        break;

}
echo bcmul($price, $quantity, 2);
// 87.5

?>
```

Comment: Because the second decimal is a zero...it's no more preceise than 87.5.  If you specified 3, and the result was 87.501, then the zero would be included.

Comment: I was under the impression the scale displays whichever number you throw at it. Should I use `number_format()` to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/function.number-format.php) instead of [`bcmul()`](http://php.net/manual/function.bcmul.php)

```
echo number_format(bcmul($price, $quantity, 2), 2, '.'); // forces to output always 2 diget after .
```

Comment: I had this originally but decided to start using the `bcmath` functions consistently. Is there no other alternative?

Comment: You can use number_format() after using bcmul(). number_format() is for output formatting.

Comment: I put that together after seeing @Francis Gilbert's response. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is rounding the 87.50 as 87.5 would be the same. To fix, you'd need:

```
number_format("87.50",2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathmatically 87.5 is 87.50. If you need additional number padding, you can use `number_format` or `money_format` to display the extra 0

Answer (score 0):

for php < 7.3 use

```
$val = bcmul('2', '5', 2);
$val = number_format($val, 2, '.', '');

// $val = "10.00"
```

or use php >= 7.3 it fixed

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php#refsect1-function.bcmul-notes